# Uninitialized constant Phash

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, phash

I started to learn ruby ​​recently. I trying to use a library pHash on ruby for my own project. I trying during for 2 days, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.I included old and new versions library, I installed in local directory and home directory. I got constantly error on compile ruby and in command line ubuntu. At last I tried to use a bundler/inline and got next error.

[image]

Code here:

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
      source 'https://rubygems.org'
      gem 'pHash', require: 'ffi'
      gem 'rspec', require: false
    end

Phash::Text.new('first.txt') % Phash::Text.new('second.txt')
```

The last line I take from documentation.

Comment: This gem is dead. Try https://github.com/toy/phamilie or https://github.com/Nakilon/dhash-vips

Answer (score 0):

`require: 'ffi'` seems unlikely to do what you need... and indeed the examples in the documentation all include a specific `require` call first. The one you referenced looks like this in full:

```
require 'phash/text'

Phash::Text.new('first.txt') % Phash::Text.new('second.txt')
```

Comment: Well.. It doesn't work. Now I get next error. 
"Specify path to pHash library using PHASH_LIB environment variable. Could not open library 'pHash': pHash: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. (LoadError)
Could not open library 'libpHash.so': libpHash.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @JustName "You can specify path to pHash library explicitly using environment variable like `PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib`." (From the documentation)